# Kafka 0.9.0 and Spark Streaming 2.1.0: kafka.cluster.BrokerEndPoint cannot be cast to kafka.cluster.Broker

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm having problems with Spark Streaming 2.1.0, Scala 2.11.8 and Kafka 0.9.0. These are my dependencies:

```
 libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.1.0",
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-8" % "2.1.0",
    "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.9.0.0",
    "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.9.0.0"
),
```

This is my Spark Streaming Code to connect to the Kafka Server:

```
 def initializeKafka(ssc: StreamingContext, topic: String):
   InputDStream[(String,String)] = {
    val lioncubConf = Configuration

    val kafkaParams = Map[String, String](
      "metadata.broker.list" -> "debian:9092",
      "group.id" -> "222",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "smallest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> "false")

    KafkaUtils.createDirectStream
      [String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, Set(topic))
}
```

At the moment I'm running `kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0` at a Debian VM which I have set as "debian" in my `/etc/hosts`. It's a single broker. The topic was created following the Kafka Quickstart (https://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation/#quickstart). I have to use this version of kafka, because it's the version on the cluster where I have to deploy my software.

I'm facing the following Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: kafka.cluster.BrokerEndPoint cannot be cast to kafka.cluster.Broker
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$6$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:97)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:97)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:94)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:94)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:93)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.foreach(Set.scala:94)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:93)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$2.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:92)
at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:522)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.findLeaders(KafkaCluster.scala:92)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getLeaderOffsets(KafkaCluster.scala:186)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getLeaderOffsets(KafkaCluster.scala:168)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaCluster.getEarliestLeaderOffsets(KafkaCluster.scala:162)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$$anonfun$5.apply(KafkaUtils.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$$anonfun$5.apply(KafkaUtils.scala:211)
at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:522)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:211)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:484)
at hfu.lioncub.KafkaInitializer$.initializeKafka(KafkaInitializer.scala:22)
at hfu.lioncub.LioncubStream$.main(LioncubStream.scala:44)
at hfu.lioncub.LioncubStream.main(LioncubStream.scala)
```

It seems to be a version conflict. But I can't figure it out. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing the Kafka Version to `org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.8.2.1` and removed `"org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.9.0.0"`. Then I had to problem that Configurations for hdfs couldn't be resolved, which I also fixed by adding a MergeStrategy: `case PathList("META-INF", "services", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem") => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines`.